# takes in integers in the same line and square the integers and sum them all up. Exiting with a enter key

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumSqDigits1(int num);

int main()
{
 int num, result;
 printf("Enter a number: \n");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 printf("sumSqDigits1(): %d\n", sumSqDigits1(num));

}
int sumSqDigits1(int num){
    int count,sum = 0,square,input;
    char end;
    while (end != '\n'){
        scanf("%d",&input);// enter a number 3418
        sum = sum + (input * input); //3*3+4*4+1*1+8*8. 
        scanf("%c",&end); //exiting when enter key is press?
    }
    return sum;
}
```

//Need some advice on how to implement this as i want 1 line when entering the numbers

Comment: Suggestion: use [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the line into a string, then parse the integers from the string.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comment, you should take input as a char array and then iterate over character one by one extracting digits from it and adding squared digit to sum. You can find a small example below.

Note that I haven't considered corner cases for input validation, I think you should be able to do it yourself ;-)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sumSqDigits1(char input[], int size);

int main()
{
 int num, result;
 char input[100];
 while (1) {
     printf("Enter a number: ");
     // Take whole line as input using fgets()
     fgets(input, 100, stdin);

     // If user presses '\n', terminate program
     if (input[0] == '\n') {
         printf("Exiting...\n");
         break;
     }

     input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0'; // trim trailing '\n'
     
     printf("sumSqDigits1(): %d\n", sumSqDigits1(input, 100));
 }
}

int sumSqDigits1(char input[], int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0' && i < size; i++) {
        // Get integer value of digit by subtracting from '0'. Checkout their
        // ASCII values: https://asciichart.com/
        int digitFromChar = input[i] - '0';
        sum += (digitFromChar * digitFromChar);
    }

    return sum;
}
```